# Cordova New Media Record save to directory

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Working on a recording app with Cordova and using `new Media` for recording. I'm also using `cordoba-file-plugin` for creating directories etc. So when the app initialising I'm running

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
   app.root = fs;
}, function(error){
   console.log(error);
});
```

And then I'm running this code:

```
app.root.root.getDirectory('appname', {create:true}, function(dirEntry){
   dirEntry.getDirectory('recordings', {create:true}, function(subDirEntry) {
      app.recordings = subDirEntry;
   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
}, function(error){
   console.log(error);
});
```

Then I have the recoding script and I would like to save the file directly to `app.recordings`, the directory I created for this app. But nothing shows up.

```
var path = app.recordings.nativeURL;
var filename = path + "recording-" + new Date().getTime() + ".mp3";
var mediaRec = new Media(filename, app.services.audio.success, app.services.audio.error);
mediaRec.startRecord();
mediaRec.stopRecord();
```

I keep getting a tmprecording-12351834581925.3gp in root.

Answer (score 3):

**On device ready**

```
if(device.platform == "iOS"){
   app.path = cordova.file.tempDirectory;
   app.extension = ".wav";
   app.mimeType = "audio/wav";
} else if(device.platform == "Android"){
   app.path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
   app.extension = ".amr";
   app.mimeType = "audio/amr";
}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(app.path, function(fileSystem){
   fileSystem.getDirectory("AppName", {create:true},function(dirEntry){
      dirEntry.getDirectory("Recording", {create:true} , function(subEntry){
            app.recording = subEntry.nativeURL;
         }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
         });
   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
},function(error){
   console.log(error);
});
```

**Then on recording**

```
var filename = app.recording + new Date().getTime() + app.extension;
var mediaRec = new Media(filename, success, error);
```

The files are now saved in a preferred location where I now have control and access to the files.

**Reading files in Recordings**

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(app.recording ,function (fileSystem) {
   var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
   reader.readEntries(function (entries) {
      console.log(entries);
      //loop all entries
   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
}
```

Comment: Plus one, just for the recorder directory path.